# MySQL - Month SELECT command

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to solve a MySQL exercise and I am having issues with finding the right command.

There is a table called 'orders' with the following columns: `orderNumber`, `orderDate`, `requiredDate`, `shippedDate`, `status` and `customerNumber`. 
The question says to show the orders payed in the summer (columns to be shown: `orderNumber` and `orderDate`).

I think the answer should be something like this, but I can't figure out how to precise the month (probably something with `IN` or `BETWEEN` but I can't solve it):

```
SELECT COUNT(orderDate), orderNumber
FROM orders
GROUP BY orderNumber;
```

Comment: Why the aggregation?

Comment: Use BETWEEN using the first of the first summer month and the last of the last summer month. Skip the aggregation and think about what constitutes a payed order.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would like to find another solution as there are orders in this table from lots of different years.

Comment: @stickybit You are right. It’s not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Use the MONTH function to get the month for the date and compare it with the summer period using BETWEEN

```
SELECT orderNumber, orderDate
FROM Orders
WHERE MONTH(w) BETWEEN x AND y
  AND status = z
```

- w is the date column to use, not sure which one it is
- x & y represents start and end month of summer where you live
- z the status the order gets when it’s paid

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear how you distinguish between paid and unpaid but, anyway,  for select the order, if you want the order list you  could use

```
SELECT orderDate, orderNumber
FROM orders
where orderDate between str_to_date('2018-06-21', '%Y-%m-%d') 
    and str_to_date('2018-09-21', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

the aggregationion seems not necessary to me  ..

Comment: And how do you distinguish between paid and unpaid orders?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  .. correct .. answer  updated  adding the request  to OP

Comment: It doesn’t seem to work. The idea is that the orders are from many different years, not only 2018.

Comment: then  updated your answer  add  a proper (clear) data sample and the expected  result  ..